# Can't link ionic app to ionic pro account

Tags: ionic-framework, jhipster

I have a monolith jhispter app and an ionic-jhipster app both working fine together (Thanks to Matt Raible and JHipster team). And I'm not sure if my problem has anything to do with JHipster.

**Since I'm working on windows, I thought maybe I'd be better to use Ionic Pro cloud services to build my app for ios and Android. Please correct me if I'm wrong.**

Here is the process I went through:

1-I added my Ionic app on GitHub. So, I'm using GitHub as my Source Control

2-I used "ionic ssh setup" command to create SSH public/private keys and I believe it took care of generating the keys and putting them in the right place **I guess I didn't have to generate the SSH keys since it could work just by my user name and password too. Is that right?**

3-I went to my app's folder and used "ionic link" to link my existing app to my Ionic Pro dashboard

4-In answer to existing app or new app (which was not clear to me what it's asking for), I chose new app since GaëlMarziou helped me in the comments section to understand there should be an app already created in my Ionic Pro so I can link my local app to it. It took me a while so I understood this prompt is asking about the dashboard app not my local app. I chose "new" since it was the first time I was using my Ionic Pro account and I had no app on it.

5-Then it asked about the source control and I chose GitHub and provided the credentials

6-Then it showed me a list of my repositories on GitHub so I can choose one. But before I do anything it just jumped out with no error/success messages. And I considered it done since I had the same names for my app and GitHub repository and I thought maybe it was smart enough to find the correct repository.

Now, I can see an app in my Ionic Pro dashboard but the build and commit history is empty and it looks like the app is not linked yet.

I tried "git push origin master" to build my app when I was in my Ionic app folder. **I assume "origin" would work for any git repository, am I right?** It tells me everything is up-to-date and nothing happens in my Ionic Pro dashboard.

Comment: Have you created your app in Ionic Pro before linking it? See https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/basics/getting-started/?wvideo=fnfuwtyenb

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you! After reading your comment I realized that linking a locally existing app still needs an app in Ionic pro. So I chose creating a new app while prompted by CLI. But it's still confusing and not working. My app is on GitHub and it also looks available on Ionic pro dashboard. But to make sure everything is alight, I tried "git push ionic master" the same way it was used in the video I found in the link you sent me. But it told me: "fatal: 'ionic' does not appear to be a git repository" which makes sense, because I don't have a repository named Ionic here

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Maybe there is no Ionic repository since I'm using GitHub

Comment: I used "git push origin master". But I guess my app is not linked yet. I got no errors while doing the link process and also no success messages. It just stopped and jumped out of the process and I considered it done. But now, there is no "commit" in the history of Master branch on Ionic pro dashboard. To me it looks like it's an empty app and my local app is not linked

Comment: Have you tried to configure 2 remotes in git? One for github named "origin" and one for ionic pro that you could name "ionic" so that you can 'git push ionic master'. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: My Ionic application is named "Ionic4j". I added it to GitHub and the repository is now available on GitHub if that's what remote means. So, I'm using GitHub as my Source Control and want to use Ionic Pro to build my Ionic application using cloud services since I'm working on windows and I thought it might be easier to use cloud services like Ionic pro to build apps for ios and android. Do I need any more repositories/remotes? Am I on the right track or I'm just confused and doing silly things? :)

Comment: I just updated the question and provided more details

Comment: Have you contacted Ionic support?

Comment: Not yet, wanted to get some feedback from experts here first and then go for that. So, you believe I should let them know about it?

Comment: Well you paid for it, so why not ask their experts ?

Comment: It's a free account. I'll talk to them. You've already helped me a lot. Thanks